# OpenGL rotating a camera around a point

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation, 3d

In OpenGL I'm trying to rotate a camera around a point, with camera being distance r from the point and facing the point when it rotates.  In other words, I want the camera to move along the circumference  of a circle at a radius r from the center, with the camera facing the center at any point along the circumference.

Lets say that in 3d space the center of the circle is (3, 0, 3);

I've tried:

```
// move to center of circle    
glTranslatef(-3, 0, -3)
// move a distance away from the circle
glTranslatef(0, 0, r);
// rotate along the y "up" axis
glRotatef(CameraAngle, 0, 1, 0);
```

where CameraAngle is the degrees being moved around the circle.

My end result is the camera is still rotating along the origin, not the center of the circle.  Can anyone help me fix this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to either:

- rotate the camera around the origin and then translate it (*)

or:

- use `gluLookAt` to keep the camera pointing at the center of the circle

(*) rotation functions normally rotate about the origin.  To rotate around another point `P` you have to:

- translate(-P)
- rotate
- translate(P)

Comment: i've done that using "quaternions prototype" (simple method within my Vector class which rotates one around other vector). looks more flexible =)

Answer (score 13):

it is a little confusing, but i think you should:

```
// move camera a distance r away from the center
glTranslatef(0, 0, -r);

// rotate 
glRotatef(angley, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(anglex, 1, 0, 0);

// move to center of circle    
glTranslatef(-cx, -cy, -cz)
```

note the order must NOT be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with all the trouble of rotating the camera and not rotate the scene itself?
It's much more straight forward. just rotate the modelview matrix around the origin. You'll get the exact same result.

Comment: The camera in this case is implemented by rotating the model view matrix, so rotating the modelview matrix is the same as rotating the camera. Rotating the scene involves using different vertex positions etc... I thought your post was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I find problems like this much easier to solve with gluLookAt().  You define a path for the camera (a circle is easy!) and keep the "center" point fixed (i.e. the thing you're looking at).

The only possible trick is defining a good up vector--but not usually too much work.  If the path and the target point are in the same plane, you can use the same up vector each time!