# opengl rotate a point around an axe

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a point which is the initial position of my light :

```
GLfloat light0Pos[4] = {0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 0.00};
```

I would like update coordinates of this point when I do a rotation around axis Y of value `roty` and a rotation around axis X of value `rotx`.

Comment: Simply change the components in the array...

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve. You can do a rotation of  an object, rotation of the camera or both. Lights usually contain a position and a vector for their direction. In a scene the light position doesn't need to be rotated.

[Rotating objects in a scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515059/how-to-rotate-a-specific-object-in-opengl)

[Rotating the camera around a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287655/opengl-rotating-a-camera-around-a-point?rq=1)

If you do want to edit the position or vector for the light just edit the values in the array
**{0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 0.00}**

Comment: "usually", Spot Light & Directional Lights uses a direction vector, though Point Lights doesn't use any direction vector.

Comment: I just want edit the position of the light. So I must use trigonometric formula ?